# Duplicate Column name error while executing mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM  

(SELECT pp.id as ppid, pp.*,tab3.*,tab2.*  FROM tab1 AS pp 
LEFT JOIN tab3 ON pp.id = tab3.name_id 
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON pp.id = tab2.name_id) AS t1

JOIN 
(
SELECT tab2.id as colname_id,tab2.*,tab3.* FROM tab2 
LEFT JOIN tab3 ON tab2.coltestconsent_id = tab3.coltestconsent_ID
) AS t2

WHERE t1.ppid = t2.colname_id;
```

Description:above query is not running its creating error:

Error Code : 1060
Duplicate column name 'id'

To make the above query work successfully I had to put column name instead of "*"
like below :

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM  

(SELECT pp.first_name,pp.id ppid,tab3.id AS coltestrisk_id,tab2.id AS coltest_id  FROM tab1 AS pp 
LEFT JOIN tab3 ON pp.id = tab3.name_id 
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON pp.id = tab2.name_id) AS t1

JOIN 
(
SELECT tab2.coltestconsent_id AS coltestconsent_id,tab3.coltestconsent_ID AS colriskconsent_id,tab2.name_id AS colname_id,tab3.name_id AS coltest_nameid FROM tab2 
LEFT JOIN tab3 ON tab2.coltestconsent_id = tab3.coltestconsent_ID
) AS t2

WHERE t1.ppid = t2.colname_id;
```

Requirement:  I want to fetch all column value of all tables. Every table has 60-80 columns . I don't want to put  column name in my query manually since they are lot of columns.

Comment: you have one more error, after "as t2" , you haven't applied "on"

Comment: @AK47: In MySQL, join predicates are optional.

Answer (score 0):

No need for derived tables:

```
SELECT t1_pp.id AS ppid, t2_tab2.id AS colname_id, *
FROM   (
              tab1 AS t1_pp 
    LEFT JOIN tab3 AS t1_tab3 ON t1_pp.id = t1_tab3.name_id 
    LEFT JOIN tab2 AS t1_tab2 ON t1_pp.id = t1_tab2.name_id
       ) JOIN (
              tab2 AS t2_tab2
    LEFT JOIN tab3 ON t2_tab3 USING (coltestconsent_id)
       ) ON t1_pp.id = t2_tab2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

**YOU  DON'T MENTION `*` LIKE YOU CODE:**

Probably because the `*` in `select *` selects `two columns name` with the same name.

```
SELECT pp.id as ppid, pp.*,tab3.*,tab2.*  FROM tab1 AS pp
```